# Polymer 2.0 syntax difference

Tags: polymer

I am new to Polymer and I am trying to clear the ideas.

I see this syntax around:

```
<script>

Polymer({
  is: 'shop-app',
  properties: {
    page: {
      type: String,
      reflectToAttribute: true,
      observer: '_pageChanged'
    },
    //...
    </script>
```

But in many tutorials (including this one from google https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/polymer-2-carousel) another syntax is used. I cannot seem to catch the difference. Why is used one instead of the other?

```
<script>

// Extend Polymer.Element base class
class MyCarousel extends Polymer.Element {

  static get is() { return 'my-carousel' }

  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
  }

}

// Register custom element definition using standard platform API
customElements.define(MyCarousel.is, MyCarousel);

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code block you have posted is the Polymer 1.x way of doing things. You can still actually use those elements in Polymer 2.0, by importing the `polymer/polymer.html` as well as `polymer/polymer-elements.html`. They are known as hybrid components.

The class type syntax came along with javascript ES6. Not all javascript engines understand ES6 yet, so it is often necessary to use Babel to transpile the ES6 code to ES5.

Polymer 2.0 embraces ES6 with gusto and so you can now use the code in the second code block you posted to write Polymer elements. This new way is meant to show the developer just how close you are working to the browser components. Polymer.Element is actually an extension of a HTMLElement, which is the basic building block of elements in a browser.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you provide link to the documentation to argument your answer? In that case I will mark this question as solved

Comment: If you peruse the README on the github page: [link](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/7836e6c45035f789479d69ea05ac4e9070f6dafe/README.md), it explains the imports above in more detail under the headings "1.0 Compatibility Layer" and "2.0 ES6 Class-based Syntax". It also explains the extending of HTMLElement at the top under "Polymer in 1 Minute"